# Programming approach to calculating Lowest/Highest Combined Surface(s)

Tags: python, algorithm, 3d, geometry

## Lowest/Highest Combined Surface(s)

I'm looking for a methodology (and/or preferably a software approach) to create what I'm calling the Lowest (or highest) combined surface for a set of polygons.

So if our input was these two polygons that partially overlap and definitely intersect
[image]

My **Lowest Combined** output would be these three polygons

[image: ![](threePoly.png)]

Given a number of "surfaces" (3d polygons)

We've gone through a variety of approaches and the best solution we could come up with involved applying a point grid to each polygon and performing calculations to return the lowest sets of points at each grid location.  The problem is that the original geometry is lost in this approach which doesn't give us a working solution.

#### Background

I'm looking at a variety of "surfaces" that can be represented by 3d faces (cad Speak) or polygons and usually are distributed in a shapefile (`.shp`).  When there are two surfaces that interact I'm interested in taking either the lowest combined or highest combined surface.  I'm able to do this in CAD by manually tracing out new polygons for the interaction zones - but once I get into more than a handful of surfaces this becomes too labor intensive.

#### The current Approach

My current approach which falls somewhere in the terrible category is to generate a point cloud from each surface on a `1m` grid and then do a grid cell based comparison of the points.

I do this by using **AutoCAD Civl 3D's** surface Generation Tools to create a TIN from each polygon surface and then using its Surface.  This is then exported to a `1m DEM` file which I believe is a gridded output format.

Next each `DEM` file is brought into **Global Mapper** where I generate a single point at the center of each "elevation grid cell".  Next this data is exported to a `.csv` file where each point contains a variety of attributes such as what the name of the surface this point came from and what its altitude is

Next once I have a set of `CSV` files I run them through a python script that will export the lowest point (and associated attributes) at each grid.  I do everything in `UTM` because the `UTM` grid is based on meters and it makes everything easier.

Lastly we bring the point file back into global mapper - coloring each point by what surface it started from.

There a variety of issues with this approach - sometimes things don't line up perfectly and there is a variety of cleanup I have to do

[image: ![](output_wiht_attirbutes.png)]

Also the edges end up being jagged - as is the case because I've converted nice straight lines into a point cloud

Alternatively we came up with a similar approach in **Arc GIS** using the **Surface Comparison tool**, however it had similar limitations to what we ran into with my approach.

What I'm looking for is a way to do this automatically with a variable number of inputs.  I'm willing to use just about any tool to have this done, as it seems like it shouldn't be too difficult a process

## Software?

When I look at this problem from a programmers point of view it looks rather straight forward - but I'm at a total loss how to proceed.  I'm assuming Stack Overflow is the correct stack exchange for this question - but if it should be somewhere else - I'm happy to move it to a different exchange.

I wasn't sure if something like Mathematica (which i have zero experience) with could handle this situation or whether there was some fancy 3d math library in python that could chop polygons up by how they interact and then give me the lowest for co-located polys.

In any case I'm willing to try anything out so please if you have an idea of what tools and/or libraries I can use to do this please share!  I have to assume that there is SOMETHING out there that can handle this type of 3d geometric processing
Thanks

**EDIT**
Because the commenters seem confused I am not asking for code - I am asking for methodologies, libraries, support tools, or even software packages that can perform these operations.  I plan to write software to do this, however, I am hoping I don't need to pull out my trig books and write all these operations by hand.  I have to assume there is somebody out there that has dealt with something similar before.

Comment: @depperm "In any case I'm willing to try anything out so please if you have an idea of what tools and/or libraries I can use to do this please share!" ... don't think he's asking for code.

Comment: A very elaborate question disguising a request for code. Isn't this off topic?

Comment: I'm not asking for code - I'm asking for libraries or something that does 3d polygon magic that i can write code with.  I have been unable to find anything - and yet GPU's seem to do this often

Comment: Have you thought of sympy?http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/index.html

Comment: How to choose the right combination of generated polygons ?, I am using blender 3d and it gives me many options (I leave an example image) ... what is the algorithm to choose?[![test image][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8f8x.png

Comment: Is blender scriptable?

Comment: @MishaVacic Thanks for the idea but it says: "Currently there are no plans for extending the module to three dimensions, but it certainly would be a good addition. This would probably involve a fair amount of work since many of the algorithms used are specific to two dimensions."